# stopPropagation doesnt work on chrome+live methods

Tags: jquery, google-chrome

In these two items i call a specific function

```
$('.item >li> div').click(function (e) {
$('.item .time').live('mousedown', function (e) {
     e.stopPropagation();
```

In opera, firefox this works fine. In chrome when i click the time div my function runs twice instead of once. 
In [jquerys Additional Notes](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/) it mentions this

> Since the .live() method handles
>   events once they have propagated to
>   the top of the document, it is not
>   possible to stop propagation of live
>   events. Similarly, events handled by
>   .delegate() will always propagate to
>   the element to which they are
>   delegated; event handlers on any
>   elements below it will already have
>   been executed by the time the
>   delegated event handler is called.

ok fine, but how do i stop my function from being run twice? also if i remove the line stopPropagation firefox and opera will have the same problem.

using jquery 1.4.4

Comment: Is there a reason you're assigning a `.live()` handler inside a `click` handler? What is the overall objective that you're trying to achieve?

Comment: @patrick dw: Yes, the class is created dynamically through javascript. The objective is to get the main div and sub divs all to run an event on click.

Comment: Do you mean that if you click on one `.time` element, then *all* the other `.time` elements in the same `li > div` should also run their click handlers? A sample of the HTML structure may be help me understand.

Comment: @patrick dw: No but its parents will get the click event. I cheated and just checked with jquery what browser it is and if its chrome i just return. It works perfect ATM.

Answer (score 2):

`click` and `mousedown` are distinct events, stopping the propagation of one won't affect the other in any way. Also, live events fire after normal events, so you would have to call `stopPropagation` in the normal event handler, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

> I cheated and just checked with jquery
>   what browser it is and if its chrome i
>   just return. It works perfect ATM.

If it works with the if statement it would likely work if you removed the if statement and just returned regardless...